# Non resolvable parent POM

Tags: java, spring, maven

I got the following error:

```
The project com.TestOne:test:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\KroemerT\eclipse- 
workspace\KeydoxWeb\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.TestOne:test:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: 
Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter- 
parent:pom:2.0.6.RELEASE from/to spring-snapshot 
(http://repo.spring.io/snapshot): connect timed out and 
'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 14, column 13 -> [Help 
2]
```

I did the obvious mistake and deleted my repository in `.m2` and now getting the above error. Is there some way to fix this?

My POM is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.TestOne</groupId>
<artifactId>test</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>test-services</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>


<repositories>
    <!-- ... possibly other repository elements ... -->
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshot</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>


<dependencies>
....
```

Comment: `http://repo.spring.io/snapshot): connect timed out` - works for me. Are you behind firewall/proxy which prevents access to `http://repo.spring.io/snapshot` ?

Comment: What do I have to with that link? Sry, new to Spring and maven. I'll try that tomorrow. Got end of work now.

Comment: That link is maven repository from where your parent pom is supposed to be downloaded.

Comment: Okay, and what could be the problem if the link works fine?

Comment: There is no version `1.4.4.RELEASE` in [.../org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/](http://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/).

Comment: Could you share your pom.xml ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved my problem:

I created a settings.xml and set some proxy configuration. Did the same in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

There is no version `1.4.4.RELEASE` in http://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/.

I'd take [org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.0.6.RELEASE](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.springframework.boot%20AND%20a:spring-boot-starter-parent&core=gav) from Maven Central, where searching Maven Central for the latest version is a general advice since tutorials tend to outdate with time.

Comment: Of course there is no `1.4.4.RELEASE` in `snapshot` repository. Because snapshots are for ...snapshots. There is 1.4.4.RELEASE in release repository http://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.4.4.RELEASE/

Comment: @rkosegi I know, of course. The OP, however, tried to download 1.4.4.RELEASE from this snapshot repo in his question's original version.